# Load image from saved location Android

Tags: android

I can load image from the SD card and show it to the imageView.
Now I i am trying to save the image location in the db or local variable
next time the app runs the image should load from that location.

by default its done as following

```
android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
```

How can I save the image `url` in a variable?
How can I put that `url` value in `android:src` for the next run?

How can i do this?
pseudo code is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write in a file

AndroidManifest

```
<manifest>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

Main.java

```
String filename = "myfile";
String string = "Hello world!";
FileOutputStream outputStream;

 try 
 {
   outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   outputStream.write(string.getBytes());
   outputStream.close();
 } 
 catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must write the url of the image in a json file or text file then you read it after launch your app.

```
 ImageView bmImage = (ImageView ) findViewById(R.id.image);

 bmImage.setImageBitmap(path);
```

Comment: how do i write the location?

Comment: First test with a picture in your SD card.  bmImage.setImageBitmap("/device/test/test.png");

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative way is..
*Save location in sharedpreferences
*when application starts check that location whether exists or not
*if exists grab image url from that
*Use Shared preference if you have small amount of images
*If you want to grab multiple images than file handling will be my choice